# what is the error here exaclty

Tags: php, html

i got an error in line 24 the error says:( Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\twitter\core\classes\tweet.php on line 24)

this is the code of tweet.php

```
<?php
```

class Tweet extends User {

```
function __construct($pdo){
    $this->pdo = $pdo;
}

public function tweets($user_id){
    $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM `tweets` LEFT JOIN `users` ON `tweetBy` = `user_id` WHERE `tweetBy` = :user_id AND `retweetID` = '0' OR `tweetBy` = `user_id` AND `retweetBy` != :user_id");
    $stmt->bindParam(":user_id", $user_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->execute();
    $tweets = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

    foreach ($tweets as $tweet) {
        $likes   = $this->likes($user_id, $tweet->tweetID);
        $retweet = $this->checkRetweet($tweet->tweetID, $user_id);
        $user    = $this->userData($tweet->retweetBy);
        echo '<div class="all-tweet">
                <div class="t-show-wrap">   
                 <div class="t-show-inner">
                    '.(($retweet['retweetID'] === $tweet->tweetID OR $tweet->retweetID > 0) ? ' 
                    <div class="t-show-banner">
                        <div class="t-show-banner-inner">
                            <span><i class="fa fa-retweet" aria-hidden="true"></i></span><span>'.$user->screenName.' Retweeted</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>'
                 : '').'

                    '.((!empty($tweet->retweetMsg) && $tweet->tweetID === $retweet['tweetID'] or $tweet->retweetID > 0) ?  '
                        <div class="t-show-head">
                            <div class="t-show-img">
                                <img src="'.BASE_URL.$user->profileImage.'"/>
                            </div>
                            <div class="t-s-head-content">
                                <div class="t-h-c-name">
                                    <span><a href="'.BASE_URL.$user->username.'">'.$user->screenName.'</a></span>
                                    <span>@'.$user->username.'</span>
                                    <span>'.$retweet['postedOn'].'</span>
                                </div>
                                <div class="t-h-c-dis">
                                    '.$this->getTweetLinks($tweet->retweetMsg).'
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="t-s-b-inner">
                            <div class="t-s-b-inner-in">
                                <div class="retweet-t-s-b-inner">
                                    '.((!empty($tweet->tweetImage)) ? '
                                    <div class="retweet-t-s-b-inner-left">
                                        <img src="'.BASE_URL.$tweet->tweetImage.'"/>    
                                    </div>' : '').'
                                    <div class="retweet-t-s-b-inner-right">
                                        <div class="t-h-c-name">
                                            <span><a href="'.BASE_URL.$tweet->username.'">'.$tweet->screenName.'</a></span>
                                            <span>@'.$tweet->username.'</span>
                                            <span>'.$tweet->postedOn.'</span>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="retweet-t-s-b-inner-right-text">        
                                            '.$tweet->status.'
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>' : '

                    <div class="t-show-popup">
                        <div class="t-show-head">
                            <div class="t-show-img">
                                <img src="'.$tweet->profileImage.'"/>
                            </div>
                            <div class="t-s-head-content">
                                <div class="t-h-c-name">
                                    <span><a href="'.$tweet->username.'">'.$tweet->screenName.'</a></span>
                                    <span>@'.$tweet->username.'</span>
                                    <span>'.$tweet->postedOn.'</span>
                                </div>
                                <div class="t-h-c-dis">
                                    '.$this->getTweetLinks($tweet->status).'
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>'.
                        ((!empty($tweet->tweetImage)) ? 
                        '<!--tweet show head end-->
                        <div class="t-show-body">
                          <div class="t-s-b-inner">
                           <div class="t-s-b-inner-in">
                             <img src="'.$tweet->tweetImage.'" class="imagePopup"/>
                           </div>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                        <!--tweet show body end-->
                        ' : '').'

                    </div>').'
                    <div class="t-show-footer">
                        <div class="t-s-f-right">
                            <ul> 
                                <li><button><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-share" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></button></li>    
                                <li>'.(($tweet->tweetID === $retweet['retweetID']) ? '<button class="retweeted" data-tweet="'.$tweet->tweetID.'" data-user="'.$tweet->tweetBy.'"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-retweet" aria-hidden="true"></i><span class="retweetsCount">'.$tweet->retweetCount.'</span></button>' : '<button class="retweet" data-tweet="'.$tweet->tweetID.'" data-user="'.$tweet->tweetBy.'"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-retweet" aria-hidden="true"></i><span class="retweetsCount">'.(($tweet->retweetCount > 0) ? $tweet->retweetCount : '').'</span></button>').'</li>
                                <li>'.(($likes['likeOn'] === $tweet->tweetID) ? '<button class="unlike-btn" data-tweet="'.$tweet->tweetID.'" data-user="'.$tweet->tweetBy.'"><i class="fa fa-heart-o" aria-hidden="true"></i><span class="likesCounter">'.$tweet->likesCount.'</span></button>' : '<button class="like-btn" data-tweet="'.$tweet->tweetID.'" data-user="'.$tweet->tweetBy.'"><i class="fa fa-heart" aria-hidden="true"></i><span class="likesCounter">'.(($tweet->likesCount > 0) ? $tweet->likesCount : '').'</span></button>').'</li>
                                    <li>
                                    <a href="#" class="more"><i class="fa fa-ellipsis-h" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                                    <ul> 
                                      <li><label class="deleteTweet">Delete Tweet</label></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                </div>
                </div>';
    }
}

public function getTrendByHash($hashtag){
    $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM `trends` WHERE `hashtag` LIKE :hashtag LIMIT 5");
    $stmt->bindValue(':hashtag', $hashtag.'%');
    $stmt->execute();
    return $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
}

public function getMention($mention){
    $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare("SELECT `user_id`,`username`,`screenName`,`profileImage` FROM `users` WHERE `username` LIKE :mention OR `screenName` LIKE :mention LIMIT 5");
    $stmt->bindValue(':mention', $mention. '%');
    $stmt->execute();
    return $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
}

public function addTrend($hashtag){
    preg_match_all("/#+([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/i", $hashtag, $matches);
    if ($matches) {
        $result = array_values($matches[1]);
    }

    $sql = "INSERT INTO `trends` (`hashtag`,`createdOn`) VALUES(:hashtag, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)";

    foreach ($result as $trend) {
        if ($stmt = $this->pdo->prepare($sql)){
            $stmt->execute(array(':hashtag' => $trend));
        }
    }
}

public function getTweetLinks($tweet){
    $tweet = preg_replace("/(https?:\/\/)([\w]+.)([\w\.]+)/", "<a href='$0' target='_blink'>$0</a>", $tweet);
    $tweet = preg_replace("/#([\w]+)/", "<a href='".BASE_URL."hashtag/$1'>$0</a>", $tweet);
    $tweet = preg_replace("/@([\w]+)/", "<a href='".BASE_URL."$1'>$0</a>", $tweet);
    return $tweet;
}

public function getPopupTweet($tweet_id){
    $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM `tweets`, `users` WHERE `tweetID` = :tweet_id AND `tweetBy` = `user_id`");
    $stmt->bindParam(":tweet_id", $tweet_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->execute();
    return $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
}

public function retweet($tweet_id, $user_id, $get_id, $comment){
    $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare("UPDATE `tweets` SET `retweetCount` = `retweetCount` +1 WHERE `tweetID` = :tweet_id");
    $stmt->bindParam(":tweet_id", $tweet_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->execute();

    $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO `tweets` (`status`, `tweetBy`,`tweetImage`, `retweetID`, `retweetBy`, `postedOn`,`likesCount`,`retweetCount`,`retweetMsg`) SELECT `status`,`tweetBy`,`tweetImage`,`tweetID`,:user_id,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,`likesCount`,`retweetCount`,:retweetMsg FROM `tweets` WHERE `tweetID` = :tweet_id");
    $stmt->bindParam(":user_id", $user_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->bindParam(":retweetMsg", $comment, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(":tweet_id", $tweet_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->execute();
}

public function checkRetweet($tweet_id, $user_id){
    $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM `tweets` WHERE `retweetID` = :tweet_id AND `retweetBy` = :user_id OR `tweetID` = :tweet_id AND `retweetBy` = :user_id");
    $stmt->bindParam(":tweet_id", $tweet_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->bindParam(":user_id", $user_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->execute();
    return $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}

public function addLike($user_id, $tweet_id, $get_id){
    $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare("UPDATE `tweets` SET `likesCount` = `likesCount` +1 WHERE `tweetID` = :tweet_id");
    $stmt->bindParam(":tweet_id", $tweet_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->execute();

    $this->create('likes', array('likeBy' => $user_id, 'likeOn' => $tweet_id));
}

public function unlike($user_id, $tweet_id, $get_id){
    $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare("UPDATE `tweets` SET `likesCount` = `likesCount` -1 WHERE `tweetID` = :tweet_id");
    $stmt->bindParam(":tweet_id", $tweet_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->execute();

    $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare("DELETE FROM `likes` WHERE `likeBy` = :user_id AND `likeOn` = :tweet_id");
    $stmt->bindParam(":user_id", $user_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->bindParam(":tweet_id", $tweet_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->execute();
}

public function likes($user_id, $tweet_id){
    $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM `likes` WHERE `likeBy` = :user_id AND `likeOn` = :tweet_id");
    $stmt->bindParam(":user_id", $user_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->bindParam(":tweet_id", $tweet_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->execute();
    return $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}
```

}
?>

and line 24 means this line

```
                    <span><i class="fa fa-retweet" aria-hidden="true"></i></span><span>'.$user->screenName.' Retweeted</span>
```

and i'm don't know what is the problem exactly, anyone help please?

Comment: `$user` clearly isn't an object

Comment: how can i solve it ? @JohnConde

Comment: @Kx2000x return a user object in the `$this->userData` method

Comment: learn me please i mean what should i do ? @JimL

Comment: Check your userData, which may not be returning a valid user from the `retweetBy` ID. But my guess is that you're trying to get the object of a user that retweets, when the current tweet hasn't actually been retweeted. You need to verify from $retweet that there was a retweet before you use that new $user. I haven't looked too closely but if you believe that you are checking for that condition, then your logic is probably faulty.

Comment: @TonyG uhh will check if there is any suggestion to me tell me please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check availability of **$user** before using it as an object:

```
foreach ($tweets as $tweet) {
    $likes   = $this->likes($user_id, $tweet->tweetID);
    $retweet = $this->checkRetweet($tweet->tweetID, $user_id);
    $user    = $this->userData($tweet->retweetBy);
    echo '<div class="all-tweet">
            <div class="t-show-wrap">   
             <div class="t-show-inner">
                '.(($user && ($retweet['retweetID'] === $tweet->tweetID OR $tweet->retweetID > 0)) ? ' 
                <div class="t-show-banner">
                    <div class="t-show-banner-inner">
                        <span><i class="fa fa-retweet" aria-hidden="true"></i></span><span>'.$user->screenName.' Retweeted</span>
                    </div>
                </div>'
             : '').'

                '.(($user && !empty($tweet->retweetMsg) && $tweet->tweetID === $retweet['tweetID'] or $tweet->retweetID > 0) ?  '
                    <div class="t-show-head">
                        <div class="t-show-img">
                            <img src="'.BASE_URL.$user->profileImage.'"/>
                        </div>
                        <div class="t-s-head-content">
                            <div class="t-h-c-name">
                                <span><a href="'.BASE_URL.$user->username.'">'.$user->screenName.'</a></span>
                                <span>@'.$user->username.'</span>
                                <span>'.$retweet['postedOn'].'</span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="t-h-c-dis">
                                '.$this->getTweetLinks($tweet->retweetMsg).'
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="t-s-b-inner">
                        <div class="t-s-b-inner-in">
                            <div class="retweet-t-s-b-inner">
                                '.((!empty($tweet->tweetImage)) ? '
                                <div class="retweet-t-s-b-inner-left">
                                    <img src="'.BASE_URL.$tweet->tweetImage.'"/>    
                                </div>' : '').'
                                <div class="retweet-t-s-b-inner-right">
                                    <div class="t-h-c-name">
                                        <span><a href="'.BASE_URL.$tweet->username.'">'.$tweet->screenName.'</a></span>
                                        <span>@'.$tweet->username.'</span>
                                        <span>'.$tweet->postedOn.'</span>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="retweet-t-s-b-inner-right-text">        
                                        '.$tweet->status.'
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>' : '

                <div class="t-show-popup">
                    <div class="t-show-head">
                        <div class="t-show-img">
                            <img src="'.$tweet->profileImage.'"/>
                        </div>
                        <div class="t-s-head-content">
                            <div class="t-h-c-name">
                                <span><a href="'.$tweet->username.'">'.$tweet->screenName.'</a></span>
                                <span>@'.$tweet->username.'</span>
                                <span>'.$tweet->postedOn.'</span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="t-h-c-dis">
                                '.$this->getTweetLinks($tweet->status).'
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>'.
                    ((!empty($tweet->tweetImage)) ? 
                    '<!--tweet show head end-->
                    <div class="t-show-body">
                      <div class="t-s-b-inner">
                       <div class="t-s-b-inner-in">
                         <img src="'.$tweet->tweetImage.'" class="imagePopup"/>
                       </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <!--tweet show body end-->
                    ' : '').'

                </div>').'
                <div class="t-show-footer">
                    <div class="t-s-f-right">
                        <ul> 
                            <li><button><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-share" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></button></li>    
                            <li>'.(($tweet->tweetID === $retweet['retweetID']) ? '<button class="retweeted" data-tweet="'.$tweet->tweetID.'" data-user="'.$tweet->tweetBy.'"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-retweet" aria-hidden="true"></i><span class="retweetsCount">'.$tweet->retweetCount.'</span></button>' : '<button class="retweet" data-tweet="'.$tweet->tweetID.'" data-user="'.$tweet->tweetBy.'"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-retweet" aria-hidden="true"></i><span class="retweetsCount">'.(($tweet->retweetCount > 0) ? $tweet->retweetCount : '').'</span></button>').'</li>
                            <li>'.(($likes['likeOn'] === $tweet->tweetID) ? '<button class="unlike-btn" data-tweet="'.$tweet->tweetID.'" data-user="'.$tweet->tweetBy.'"><i class="fa fa-heart-o" aria-hidden="true"></i><span class="likesCounter">'.$tweet->likesCount.'</span></button>' : '<button class="like-btn" data-tweet="'.$tweet->tweetID.'" data-user="'.$tweet->tweetBy.'"><i class="fa fa-heart" aria-hidden="true"></i><span class="likesCounter">'.(($tweet->likesCount > 0) ? $tweet->likesCount : '').'</span></button>').'</li>
                                <li>
                                <a href="#" class="more"><i class="fa fa-ellipsis-h" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                                <ul> 
                                  <li><label class="deleteTweet">Delete Tweet</label></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            </div>
            </div>';

}
```